# What should I look for when getting a web host for a Wordpress site and php API's?

Tags: php, web-server, hosting, web-hosting, web

I am an iOS developer and I want to expand and get a server (not to buy it, web hosting...i guess). I want a place where to put a site(probably WordPress site&blog), and a place where I can put my API's for mobile applications. 
Money really are a problem so I was looking for something cheaper(for beginning) and i found something..but I did not fount much stuf.
[**this**](http://www.xservers.ro/web-hosting.php) looked ok...for me (the 1.15E per month obviously :) ) Is this ok?

My real question is: **For what available services should I look for getting a web host where to put a site with a Wordpress theme and a place for php API's for my mobile applications?**

I'm very new to this and I know nothing so any explications would be welcomed. I do not want to make something big for now, something ok would be more than enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress and general PHP websites don't really have any 'special' requirements. A typical shared hosting account running on a LAMP base is the most common option in the world. If you encounter performance problems then you can rent a dedicated server or a VPS and run your own LAMP web server on it.

LAMP means Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP and is the foundation of requirements for probably 75% of websites out there.

Wordpress requires PHP and MySQL so any shared hosting account that supports those will be fine as a starting point.

Just remember that cheap hosting accounts are cheap because there will be 100's of customers on the same server, each with their own user account and vhost. Things can get slow and often do which is why shared hosting is only recommended for small sites with low amounts of traffic.

If your API for your mobile app's is SQL database heavy then you'll be wanting to move to some kind of dedicated hosting pretty quickly to get off a shared SQL instance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply! No, it won't be SQL Database heavy only small stuff for begining. How about **Cloud Web Hosting**? I saw this: http://www.xservers.ro/web-hosting.php and the **Standard** package I would like to know if it's what I need.    **Or** what i need is this http://www.xservers.ro/vps.php ? Sorry for my noob questions  but I know nothing about this. If you also have some links where I can read about it would be welcomed.

Comment: @SilviuSt Yes that standard package will do for a starting point.

Comment: And the two links I've included in the comment. What are the differences between the two?

Comment: @SilviuSt a VPS is a virtual server that take a slice of resources on a physical server such as RAM, CPU, Disk and provides you with a full operating system that you can configure applications on yourself such as Apache, PHP and MySQL. Its your own virtual server in the cloud.